# How to mock msg['to'] key in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is it possible to mock ( or to replace with my email id) the below code to avoid triggering email to unknown person in my test code.

```
msg['to'] = 'test@gmail.com'
```

where msg is the object of MIMEText of email.mime.text module in python.

I am using smtplib module to trigger the email.

Comment: Consider using a service like [mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) as a SMTP server to avoid sending real emails during testing

Comment: You should be mocking `smtplib` or at least [`SMTP.sendmail()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) instead of trying to change only the `to` address. In that case, your test emails only go to the `to_addr` of the mock and don't need to be specified; or you could just overwrite the `to_addrs` parameter.